# Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found please helpme

Tags: flutter, firebase

i have a problem

```
   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
}
```

}

the error problem is
"Build file 'C:\Users\muham\altamazee\android\app\build.gradle' line: 26"

this line code 15-32
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MQwo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Those dependencies should be added to the build.gradle in the root android folder at `C:\Users\muham\altamazee\android\build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
}
```

Also, you should add the below line to the end of the build.gradle file in the android/app directory `C:\Users\muham\altamazee\android\app\build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Do not forget to increase the minimum SDK version in your `android\app\build.gradle` to at least 19 but 21 preferably.

```
defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        // other configurations can be here
    }
```

Comment: thankyouu the problem is solve, but ihave new problem
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:21.2.0] C:\Users\muham\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\8633cdbb31c4e3bc3e11784e197becbf\transformed\jetified-firebase-analytics-ktx-21.2.0\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
 Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
  or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
  or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.firebase.analytics.ktx"

Comment: in your C:\Users\muham\altamazee\android\app\build.gradle, set the minSdkVersion to 21 by adding minSdkVersion 21 to your defaultConfig in the said gradle file. Chances are yours is already set to some default. Change the value to 21.

Comment: @MuhammadFerdy i have updated my answer to reflect the change that should be made to the minimum SDK version.